# How to acces 127 from my server?

Tags: 14.04

I install a patch on my server ubuntu. Solr, and the guide say: "after instalation please access solar at 127.0.0.1:8080(an example) how can access this adress from my compture ?

I have Mac OS x.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it running on virtualbox, parallel or vmware ?

Comment: open a browser and insert it?

Comment: @JoakimKoed no, I use ssh to connect to my server, but the guide advice to acces 127.0.0.1:80 to set it up.

Comment: Then you probably just need to open `http://server-ip` and you are good to go.  I assume since you ssh, you know the IP.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is by convention the "loopback" address of the system. In other words, on any computer, it is always present and is the computer itself (the very short ping delays will confirm this). It corresponds to your "lo" network interface.

Comment: Its about a dedicate server here.

Comment: Just use the "normal" address of the server (the one assigned to its eth0 interface, likely). The suggestion to use 127.0.0.1 to check the solr server is just telling to check the server from the server itself (and using an address which is the same for everybody). Don't read more in that than there is.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the IP address of your server, if it is a local server, you should be good to go, if not, you would need to port forward that port to the address.  Do comment if you need further help.

Comment: The server is not local, I have the ip address can advice how to do it ?

Comment: Alright, Do you have access to the firewall connected to the server?  You would need to port forward your port... lets start with that.

Comment: Hm... not sure, how can I check it ?

Answer (score 0):

From your server's terminal type `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -` to get it's external IP address.

Then from your computer open a browser and go to `http://<IP>:8080`. If you don't get any results, provide the output of `netstat -peanut` from your server and `sudo ufw status`